# InitialContext lookup("java:comp/env") fails

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, jndi, tomcat9

created a dao layer where Datasource object in created in pre-process operation

```
...
public static DataSource  pcpds;
    static {
        try {
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        Context c = (Context) ic.lookup("java:comp/env");
        pcpds = (DataSource) c.lookup("jdbc/reqtracker");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
...
```

datasource properties are written in context.xml of Tomcat-9 container

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application -->
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/tomcat-web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->
<Resource 
    name="jdbc/reqtracker" auth="Container" type="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" 
    maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000" username="postgres" 
    password="postgress" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" 
    databasePlatform="org.hibernate.dialect.Postgresql9Dialect" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/reqtracker"/>
</Context>
```

exception i am getting is

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Could not create resource instance
    at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:98)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:857)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:160)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:174)
```

on windows it works fine but in linux it fails,

Comment: Why are you using two lookups when one would do?

Comment: @user207421 i used single lookup with "java:comp/env/jdbc/reqtracker" but still same exception